# What is the origin for "- the hell out of -"?

Tags: offensive-language

Sometimes expletive sentences contains these words, for example "I'll [beat the hell](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/beat+the+hell+out+of+him)/[crap](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/beat+the+hell+out+of+him) out of him"

Comment: With _crap/shit_, it’s clearly literal in origin—it’s a threat to beat someone so soundly they lose control of their bowels. That’s not so likely with _hell_, since I don’t think most people would think that we have hell inside us to begin with it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - hell here just emphasizes the action, as in  other idiomatic expressions,  what the hell are you doing, etc.

Comment: @user5768790 Well, yes—my point was that the _origin_ of using that particular word in this particular construction is clearly not literal. Unlike with _crap/shit_, “I’ll beat the hell out of you!” never in any literal sense meant “You have some hell inside you, and I am going to beat you so hard that the hell inside you is going to come out of you”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the expression ***[the hell out of](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/%E2%80%94_the_hell_out_of)***,  "*the hell*" (lower case) is used to emphasize the action you are referring to:

> - Used in verbal phrases to emphasize force, speed, etc.

***The hell*** has a long history in idiomatic expressions where its function is mainly to add emphasis to the literal meaning of the sentence. According to [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beat%20the%20hell%20out%20of%2Cbeat%20the%20crap%20out%20of%2Cbeat%20the%20shit%20out%20of&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeat%20the%20hell%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeat%20the%20crap%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeat%20the%20shit%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0) the expression "beat the hell out of" is from 1920s and precedes other similar constructions such as "beat the crap/shit out of".

In the following piece,  Professor, and ELU user John Lawler comments that:

> - To start with, "[the hell](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/thehell.html)" must be distinguished from "Hell!", or "Oh,
>     hell!", which are full utterances (traditionally, "interjections", the
>     last and least of the classical Eight Parts of Speech), the sort of
>     thing you say when you've made a mistake, had a mistake made for you, or
>     otherwise experienced the displeasure of Fortune.  They are
>     linguistically unusual in having no syntax -- "Oh, hell!" is a full
>     utterance (though hardly a 'sentence' - no subject, no verb, etc.) and
>     needs no further complement.
> - There are also some fixed phrases. "What the hell" is used to express
>     disregard for conventional procedure and precautions, in varying degrees
>     (the phrase has some of the same implications as "devil-may-care"). It
>     is usually a phrasal interjection, without further syntactic
>     ramifications: